# Why is it acceptable that publishers sell papers they didn’t pay for?

Tags: publishers

I am curious about the worldwide accepted ethics in publishing. I have never seen any other economic sector in which someone legally sold someone else's product for their own profit, apparently without paying for it in any way. I don’t intend to accuse any publisher, I just want to know how this works and why is this acceptable. Is it expected to be changed in the future? Do scientists want to change it, or is this accepted by more or less the whole community?

I admit, this question might seem to be off topic or opinion based but I don’t know where could I ask it.

Comment: Closely related, maybe duplicate: [Why are academics not paid royalties on published research papers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/109003/why-are-academics-not-paid-royalties-on-published-research-papers-in-ieee-acm-e?rq=1)

Comment: Obligatory related link: [The cost of knowledge](http://thecostofknowledge.com).

Comment: Possible explanation and obligatory [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/2025/).

Comment: Answers in comments and ensuing discussions have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83204/discussion-on-question-by-balazstoth-why-is-it-acceptable-that-publishers-sell-p). Please refrain from answering in the comments. Read [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4230/7734) before posting another comments.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

**History.**

In the dark ages (i.e., before the internet), publishers provided a valuable service. If an author has a great idea, they want the whole world to read about it and the best way to do that is to get someone to publish their work. The publisher arranges for reviews, copyedits your work, and, most importantly, prints thousands of copies and sends them to libraries and archives around the world. (Note that, legally, they need to have the rights to distribute the work, and they claim ownership of the copyediting work.) Doing all this printing, mailing, and copyediting costs a lot money and thus publishers have to charge for their services. They also make a small profit from all of this.

Fast forward to the 21st century and the picture has changed considerably. Since the arrival of personal computers and software like LaTeX and Microsoft Word, copyediting is now mostly done by authors. (Reviewers and editors are rarely paid.) And, due to the internet, it is very easy to distribute papers using websites like arXiv. Going to the library to find a print journal is now a thing of the past, as journals these days just have websites.
Of course, publishers are still doing something, but it's a fraction of what it used to be.

Publishers made a lot of sense 50 years ago, but these days their model doesn't make a lot of sense; they still collect a lot of money, even though the services could be provided much more cheaply. So why does this model persist? Firstly, publishers still own the copyrights to lots of old work that is still relevant. More importantly, publishers own the "prestige" of their journals, which means academics keep sending them their work.

Comment: I feel that this is the most honest, accurate and contemporary answer.  It really does seem to be the case that most of what publishers are providing nowadays is the prestigious venues that academics still want and need to publish in.

Comment: They never needed the copyright. They only needed licenses.

Comment: @chrylis Yes, there is no reason for them to hold exclusive rights. I just wanted to mention that there is a legitimate reason why you have to sign _something_ when publishing.

Comment: TL;DR: its a legacy adapter code

Comment: "Of course, publishers are still doing something, but it's a fraction of what it used to be." If you believe this, then the number of employees publishers have must be shrinking. Let's take Elsevier, everyone's favourite-to-hate publisher. In 1999, they employed 3600 people (https://www.relx.com/~/media/Files/R/RELX-Group/documents/reports/annual-reports/2000-annual-report.pdf p.37). In 2017, that number is 7500 (https://www.relx.com/~/media/Files/R/RELX-Group/documents/reports/annual-reports/relx2017-annual-report.pdf, p. 126). What gives?

Comment: @Allure I think Thomas meant that publishers provide less of a service for a given paper now, though I'm not sure how to quantify that. Of course, since 1999 Elsevier has grown, publishing significantly more articles and journals, and also expanded into data analytics, so as a company they're certainly still doing things, but likely somewhat different things than they used to

Comment: What role do publishers play in the peer review process? I'm sure that it could continue without them, but do they facilitate it?

Comment: @ArcanistLupus: They sometimes provide the online system through which the review process works (but that is publisher and journal-dependent). But basically all the work is done by the editors and the referees (well, and the authors). The publishers' employees input only comes to play later, when they do things like adjusting punctuation, make some stylistic adjustments, make sure the references are correctly written etc. That is my experience, at least.

Comment: Saying that the authors and editors do all the work is a bit like saying that the farmers do all the work and the grocery store does not add anything.

Comment: @Allure the explanation for the higher number of employees of the RELX group is simple: merge and acquisition of other companies (which aren't connected to research publishing, btw): https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/RELX_Group

Comment: @user97945 please check the annual reports again. I quoted only the numbers from the science and medical segment. Also, mergers need not result in higher number of employees - if they're not necessary these extra employees can always be made redundant or simply not be replaced.

Comment: *"they still collect a lot of money, even though the services could be provided much more cheaply"*... not claiming you're wrong (or right), but you really need a citation here.

Comment: @Allure if you go digging around those annual reports, you will also see that they are publishing 3-4 times as many articles as they were in 1999. (though it is fiddly, since they only sometimes mention it in the report)

Comment: @Dirk The grocery store adds very little, which is reflected in their margins: A few percent at most.

Comment: @Anyon "...as a company they're certainly still doing things, but likely somewhat different things than they used to" - I'd take that to mean that the traditional view of what publishers do is outdated, and so it's inappropriate to continue to think of publishers in that way.

Comment: *copyediting is now mostly done by authors* citation needed. I don't think it's appropriate use of research funding to fiddle with margins for hours in Latex.

Comment: @Allure But that's the whole point, they still charge in the same way they used to (for the most part).

Comment: @Dirk Grocery store margins are low because prices are driven down by competition. Certainly my diet would be very different if I had to go to a farm every time I wanted food and I live on the edge of a fairly small town.

Comment: @Allure I am not too familiar with the business side of other major publishers, so I'm not prepared to make such a general claim yet. Elsevier, on the other hand, have gone from calling themselves "the world’s leading publisher of science and health information" to "a global information analytics business", which reflects a real shift in priorities. And fair play to them, if that's where they see a real opportunity for growth.

Comment: @Allure However, even looking at the publishing arm itself it's clear that some things have changed due to the internet and increased popularity of digital typesetting. This is also part of what I consider "different things". Now, I think most of us suspect that increased overhead costs for running databases and technical support is lower than past costs for physically printing and distributing journals, but I could be wrong.

Comment: "*They also make a small profit from all of this.*" - Not always the case. I've worked as an editorial assistant for a non-profit publisher of scientific journals.

Comment: Economics is such a fun topic because everyone is an expert in how the world should work, and the one outcome that should certainly not happen is the one that has happened.

Comment: @CapeCode copyediting means editing the "copy", that is, the text. Margins, etc.,  (what the publisher does) is just formatting.

Comment: As an edit to this answer, I would suggest elaborating on what the "prestige" of a top journal publication really is: it is a project completion certificate towards tenure and promotion, or in layman's terms -- a necessity for keeping a job -- and so is not a meaningless intangible.   Often, in some fields, only publishing in a very specific list of journals will meet the academic department's requirements of quality research.  The academic associate editors of these particular journals  also thereby gain a gatekeeper power over specialties where submissions exceed journal publication slots.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Non-profit does not mean no one can make any money on it. They could still have people employed. It just means you are not allowed to take money out of the legal entity and hand it out to shareholders or other non-employed people freely as you want.

Comment: @Dirk Now replace that grocery store with an online store - and you have to pay for shipping either way (because downloading a document from the original author, or from a publisher page is no difference in shipping). So what does the grocery online store provide more compared to the free open-source farmers-market page where you can order your products directly from the farmers ?

Comment: Online store as a comparison makes a lot of sense - like Amazon makes a lot of money by selling stuff that people could sell in their own online stores commercial publishers manage to make a lot of money by selling things that people could distribute in other ways.

Answer (score 36):

It is *not* acceptable, and people are taking steps to change things, but the system has enormous inertia and many perverse incentives that must be overcome to make progress.

I would like to draw an analogy to fiction publishing.  Authors in that field have a maxim called “[Yog’s Law](https://www.thecreativepenn.com/2010/01/13/what-is-yogs-law-and-why-does-it-matter-for-authors/)” which states: *money is supposed to flow toward the author*.  This is held as a guiding principle, even in contexts where nobody expects to make a *living* by publishing their fiction: short stories, for instance, pay a pittance ([SFWA minimum rate](http://www.sfwa.org/about/join-us/sfwa-membership-requirements/#active) is US$0.06 per word, times one to ten thousand words, so $60 to $600 for a story that probably took at least 40 hours of effort to write—this is beer money, not rent money).  This principled stand is because there is a long history of “[vanity presses](https://www.sfwa.org/other-resources/for-authors/writer-beware/vanity/)” scamming authors with grandiose promises of riches and fame if they’ll just underwrite the up-front costs, and then not doing any marketing whatsoever, so nobody buys the book and the riches and fame never materialize.  Contrast this with a legitimate traditional publisher, who pays you an advance, assumes the risk that the book never sells enough copies to “earn out” that advance, and *does* do marketing.  Also contrast a printer for hire catering to self-publishers, who will tell you up front what services they do and don’t provide and how much each costs, and will *not* make any grandiose promises.  This is who you should hire to print up your family history, not a vanity press—unfortunately there isn’t an accepted alternative term for honest printers-for-hire as a group..

Academic publication is different because not only do we not expect to receive riches from publication, we don’t expect to earn anything at all in the first place (for journal articles, anyway; I understand monograph and textbook publishers do pay royalties).  Yog’s Law does not directly apply.  However, we *are* looking for a particular kind of fame, the kind where other researchers read our papers and learn things and build on them, perhaps even centuries from now.  (Much as a writer of fiction hopes that people will read their stories and find entertainment or catharsis or inspiration in them.)  For this reason, we warn against publishing in “predatory journals” that charge hefty fees, don’t do adequate peer review, and exaggerate the likelihood of anyone reading the paper or taking it all that seriously.  Predatory journals are the direct analogue of vanity presses in academic publishing.  They don’t provide value for the money.

Traditional academic publishers are *supposed* to provide value for the money they charge: peer review, copyediting and typesetting, archiving, dissemination, and perhaps most important, reputation.  Any paper published in one of the top journals or conferences in my subfield has a good chance of being worth my time, and I rely on that.  However, over the past 40 years or so (I’m not old enough to know exactly when this trend started) the publishers have become less and less interested in actually providing value, and more and more interested in extracting rents.  This is really obvious in my particular subfield, computer security: as I write this, I’ve got a paper accepted for publication in an ACM conference with a top-notch reputation.  They facilitated the peer review, but they didn’t pay the reviewers a dime; they did none of the work of copyediting and typesetting, expecting me to hand them a PDF already fully formatted; they maintain both print and online archives, but they want to either charge every reader US$25 for the privilege, or charge *me* $700 up front.  I know that this is price-gouging, because if I had published the same paper at a USENIX conference with a similar reputation and providing an identical set of editorial services, they would charge either readers or me *nothing* for the privilege.

The usual market-based solution to rent-seeking is refusal to cooperate.  So why are we all still cooperating with them?  It’s a classic [collective action problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_action_problem).  As long as most of the researchers in a field continue to publish in traditional venues, any one person can’t refuse to do so without nasty consequences for their career.  If everyone threatens to stop all at once, on the other hand, they have a chance of at least extracting concessions—in my time in graduate school, many of the top computer security conferences have moved from paywalled to open access, because our community put its collective foot down.  (Not without incident, though, as anyone else who attended the business meeting at [Oakland 2011](https://www.ieee-security.org/TC/SP2011/) can attest.)

Comment: Can you explain what is unethical about either vanity presses or academic publishers? Just saying it’s a violation of X’s law where X is someone I never heard of is a classic [appeal to authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority) fallacy. Vanity presses for one provide a service people are willing to pay for. Assuming they are not deceptive about their fee structure, I don’t see an ethical issue. With academic publishers the debate is more complicated, but if you claim they’re unethical I think the burden is on you to explain why that’s the case.

Comment: @DanRomik Especially when "Yog's Law" was coined by an author, so basically amounts to "I should get more money."

Comment: This is a good answer, but you've omitted the ray of hope! The 'open access' movement is a real thing; it even has a lengthy Wikipedia article. Unless I'm mistaken, it's still making slow but steady progress.

Comment: Now you've made me curious: What happened at the "business meeting at Oakland 2011"? Google delivers just "Occupy Oakland" results, which is probably not what you are referring to.

Comment: *Money is supposed to flow toward the author* This is a very bad "law" for academia. Do you want scientists to publish science or binge-worthy science fiction/entertainment?

Comment: Let's modify Yog's law to: pay should match added value. Where pay can also be: prestige, research resources, etc. This makes sense as an ideal, but practice proves that the implementation is hard. To the point: does the added value of the publisher match its pay?

Comment: @CL. I was referring to the [IEEE Symposium on Security and Privacy, 2011](https://www.ieee-security.org/TC/SP2011/).This conference was held in the same hotel in Oakland, California for more than thirty years, so everyone in the field called it "Oakland" for short, and still do, even though it has now outgrown that hotel and moved to a larger venue that isn't in Oakland.  I don't know if you're going to find any writeups of the business meeting I'm thinking of. It was the first step in the process of making that conference's proceedings open-access and it got a little heated, is all.

Comment: @MaxBarraclough I read recently that that EU is considering mandating that all government subsidised work is published in exclusively open-access journals. Perhaps that'll be the kick it in the pants that pushes it to take over.

Comment: @zwol If there aren't accessible accounts that you can link to of what you mean by "a little heated", then maybe it's not the best example to include?

Comment: @mbrig that’s just going to mean massive increase in pay-for-publish revenue.

Comment: Under the right circumstances vanity presses can serve a legitimate purpose. My wife's family prepared a family history that would never have been published traditionally because of limited appeal. They new exactly what they were contracting for and were happy with the results.

Comment: Wouldn't the management and employees of the for-profit publishing companies also experience "nasty consequences for their careers" if they unilaterally refused to continue in their present course? Or maybe they all have tenure to protect them?

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman I am still waiting for an explanation of when a vanity press does not “serve a legitimate purpose”. I agree with your comment and upvoted it, but at the same time I think it’s a bit misleading of you to insinuate that vanity presses are only legitimate part of the time, unless you can name any circumstances when they are not legitimate (excluding when the vanity press is being dishonest about their fees - obviously such a practice would make any business illegitimate).

Comment: @DanRomik  It depends on how you define "legitimate". If you mean in the sense of acting legally, they almost always act legally. But I was discussing the context of this answer and the many people who turn to them hoping to actually turn a profit. Especially in fiction, this is very rarely wise. They serve a useful and valid function for certain niches (family histories, narrow academic niches where the author personally knows most of the target audience, and a couple of others...), but are almost never a smart move for an author trying to turn a profit.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman people buy all sorts of products and services for all sorts of reasons, that are generally not the concern of the seller. I think it’s unfair to imply that vanity presses are ethically illegitimate or compromised because some of their customers pay for their services out of a misguided belief that they will make a profit. Unless the vanity press helped create that belief by false or misleading marketing, it is as ethical and legitimate as any other business.

Comment: @DanRomik While "false or misleading" may be going too far, the marketing for some vanity presses does target aspiring fiction writers. While perhaps "illegitimate" is too strong of a word, many of the vanity presses market to a group that would be better off without their product and thus have something of a bad reputation. I generally to defend them, but their proper and effective uses are in narrow niches. Also, we are getting way off topic, so this is the last I will say here. If you want to discuss more, feel free to message me directly or go to chat.

Comment: I have rewritten my answer to address many of the concerns brought up in this discussion.  I regret I do not have time right now to respond point by point.

Answer (score 26):

It is acceptable because there is no convincing argument why it should be unacceptable.

More generally, there is a principle of the law that people are free to enter into contractual agreements with each other, and with other legal entities such as corporations. As long as those agreements are entered into voluntarily between people of legal age, and as long as they are not deemed to be [unconscionable agreements](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/unconscionability), the agreements are legally binding, and in that sense “acceptable”. Other people who are not parties to the agreement may occasionally find them objectionable and be unhappy, but that’s their problem.

In the case of academic publishing, authors voluntarily agree to let publishers publish their papers and not pay them any royalties. I have done so myself many times. So, if I find it acceptable to not get paid royalties for my papers, and there isn’t some convincing legal argument for why my agreements with publishers should be declared unconscionable (as far as I know no one has tried to make such a case), then that’s the end of the story - it’s acceptable.

As for why I and other academics don’t have a problem with not getting royalties, I think the answer is a bit too complicated to discuss in detail here. The short answer is that writing papers is part of my job, for which I am paid a salary by my employer. Scientific papers are simply not the same as fiction or other forms of writing that people write to make money through a direct sale of their work to a body of readers. Your question assumes a premise that publishers should pay scientists for their papers because of the superficial similarity between academic publishing and other types of publishing, but that premise is simply false.

**Edit - some additional thoughts related to the (very interesting and thought provoking - thanks!) comments:**

I want to clarify that the main point of my answer is to emphasize that the answer to questions of the type “why is activity X acceptable?” is generally “it is acceptable *by default*” - that is, it’s up to opponents of X to convince everyone else that X is *not acceptable* if they believe that’s the case, and until they successfully do that, X is acceptable. I consider such questions to be [loaded questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question), since they subtly insinuate that there’s something wrong with X (without actually giving any explanation or evidence) and put people who engage in X on the defensive to “justify” their “bad” behavior. I think this loaded question effect is what makes the question “annoying” (as @Allure referred to it in a comment).

In my answer I was trying to make the point I elaborated on above. I focused on the legal aspect just because that’s what occurred to me at that moment, but the same principle applies if we were to debate the ethics of the issue (as some of the answers have done). I do acknowledge that there are some valid ethical criticisms of some of the practices of the academic publishing industry. But in my opinion those criticisms (while very interesting) are tangential to OP’s actual question. OP asked:

> Why is it acceptable that publishers sell papers they didn’t pay for?

Note that this isn’t asking why it is acceptable for some publishers to make as much money as they do (I think there are some reasonable arguments to be made that *that* may very well be unacceptable). It’s asking why it’s acceptable for authors to not get paid by publishers for their work, which is a different question. Well, as an author who voluntarily publishes his work without asking for or expecting to be paid royalties by the publisher, I find this a bit offensive, as it’s effectively accusing me of being complicit in an activity insinuated to be shady or immoral, or alternatively suggesting that I’m some sort of victim of predatory practices. I’m neither of those things.

The most correct answer in my opinion is the one in David Richerby’s answer, which is to point out that this is a loaded question based on a false premise. I expanded on David’s idea a bit more. The bottom line is that it’s acceptable for authors to let others publish their work without asking to get paid, and it’s acceptable for publishers to publish works that authors allow them to. The larger debate about academic publishing is an important one and will go on, but this question is (in my very humble opinion) not framed in a way that makes it a helpful part of that debate.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83097/discussion-on-answer-by-dan-romik-why-is-it-acceptable-that-publishers-sell-pape).

Answer (score 22):

This is not a unique situation. Consider film festivals: you make a movie, submit it to the festival which then is free to earn money by selling tickets to the spectators. There's more: prestigious festivals sell tickets *and* have submission fees for the authors.

The intangible product being sold here is reputation. Other researchers will trust your paper more if they see it in a journal they know, compared to a paper you put on your homepage. And prospective employers will prefer someone with publications in a journal over someone who only submitted papers in arXiv.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83275/discussion-on-answer-by-dmitry-grigoryev-why-is-it-acceptable-that-publishers-se).

Answer (score 20):

Your question is based on the false premise that it is only possible to sell something if you paid money for it yourself. A mining company can sell you coal without having to pay anyone for that coal. A farmer can sell you milk or eggs without paying anyone for them. A babysitter can charge you for looking after your child without paying anyone to acquire the ability to look after children.

I'm not claiming that any of these situations is an analogy for academic publishing but they do show that the idea that you can only sell something if you paid somebody for it first isn't at all true.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83098/discussion-on-answer-by-david-richerby-why-is-it-acceptable-that-publishers-sell).

Answer (score 8):

It's generally called the [tertiary sector of the economy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tertiary_sector_of_the_economy) or service sector. In developed nations it's increasingly becoming the largest part of the economy. In other words, there are many, many other examples of a company selling "something legally without paying for it in any way". For services the costs are generally associated with labor and other expenses such as rent, infrastructure, etc. rather than the wholesale price or raw material like in the situation you describe.

Publishers charge (either the authors or the readers) for the publishing service. They do not charge for content creation. Content is paid for by research grants, university salaries, etc. A possible analogy is a telephone provider. They send you a bill for the time you spend listening or reading content created by third parties without purchasing said content. Social media, Internet search engines, etc. are other examples of companies generating a profit out of content voluntarily submitted by third parties.

Personally I find it very convenient to have publishers do the publishing work for me so that I can concentrate on my research. I have to transfer my copyright? So what? I'm not in the business of publishing papers, it's only a mean to an end. I know it's field-dependent but in mine the anti-publishers argument is a fringe thing.

Answer (score 7):

I certainly can't and won't try to justify all of the practices of publishers but it is useful to consider a couple of things.

First is that the "market" for any given math paper, say, is extremely small. If the publication is on paper, then the costs, if we consider everything are very high. Even if papers aren't reviewed, they often need to be edited by a professional as not every author is native in the language of the publication. There may be, even in this age, typesetting involved. Plus printing, shipping, etc. There isn't a business model there, so no one would agree to take on publishing of your paper if all costs had to be paid. If they did, the price would have to be extremely high, reducing the market further. As a result, publishers try to avoid a number of costs including payment to authors and reviewers.

In the olden days, authors published their own "tracts" by paying a printer to do the physical stuff and not using anything but (at most) informal reviewing. They would then sell the publications themselves, sometimes on street corners, or contract with other people who did. This was fine if you were in a university town, but not so fine if you wanted a publication created a few hundred miles away. But publishers need a business model, even if it is flawed.

But also, consider a world in which everyone was properly compensated. What would be the characteristics of that world? There are several options. One is that only the most popular writers could get published as that might increase sales to the journal. Competition might ensue, even extreme competition. There would be competition by journals to publish the most popular authors, but there would also be competition between authors to *be* the most popular authors. It would be hard for a new academic to break in to such a world, perhaps.

Another possible publishing option would be the advertising model. But who would want to advertise in a journal containing abstract, possibly obscure, mathematics. Actually we do have such journals in some fields. They come and go, but they seldom pay authors in any case. And they seldom last very long (a few years at most) making old material difficult to find.

But, the fundamental reason that publishers can use a flawed model in the first place is that, in academia, money isn't the *coin of the realm*. Recognition by peers is what makes you "rich" in academe. Publishers do provide that - even for new members of the profession. But without a business model they can't and won't.

---

Let me add a note about another kind of publishing. Popular music. Since it is popular it has a large market and generates a lot of revenue. The artists *do* get paid. But it is a sad fact of life that very few musical artists, even those with platinum albums, actually make enough from their published music to live on the proceeds. Most of them make a living by going on the road and giving concerts. It never ends. That is why you still see rockers in their 70's giving concerts. Lyle Lovett has gone on record that he has never gotten a statement from his music publisher on which the bottom line was positive. The costs eat up everything - but that includes payments to stockholders, of course, without whom there would be no publishing business at all.

---

Another publishing model with flaws is textbook publishing. Textbooks now cost around $100US or even more. Of this, the author normally gets around $5. But the costs are high and the market is small. In the case of books, I've always had a professional editor, even for my native language. Figures in the book may need to be remade by a professional for use, depending on the production process. Except for a few courses like Calculus 101 or Economics 101, the market is very small. Very few authors get rich writing textbooks - though many dream to do so.

---

Let me add that in my lifetime, but long ago, there was a viable not-for-profit publishing model in Mathematics. The American Mathematical Society (AMS) is a professional membership organization. It publishes a number of journals, including the Transactions of the AMS. It is intended for longer papers, not suitable for shorter papers. Anyone could submit a paper to the journal and it would get both editorial and review services, along with, if accepted, production services. This was before the internet and so paper publishing was the only option.

If a paper was accepted there were *page charges* charged to the paper. They were quite steep, actually. If the author was grant funded then the grant source, normally the government, paid the charges. If the author had no grant, then the charges were sent to the author's institution instead. If, for any reason, the institution refused to pay the charges, they were just absorbed by the AMS and not charged to the author. Thus, the membership as a whole, paid, or page charges were high enough to cover the cases in which they wouldn't be paid. This was a form of socialism, of course, and some people hate that now.

But, for some reason, that isn't the dominant publishing model anymore. I suspect, but don't have the data, that it was simply a case that the model didn't scale well as there was an increase in the number of mathematicians and hence papers.

Non-profit, low cost models do exist, but, as I've said here and in the comments, all of the forces need to be considered in the design of such a model. If you ignore any of them, the model simply won't work for long and its defects will overcome it. But even a failed model, such as the current one, which as failed because it hasn't kept up with electronic communication, has inertia behind it that also needs to be overcome if you want to replace it with a better model.

Comment: I believe all your conclusions hinge on the axiom that academic publishing should be a business. Why do we force ourselves to contrive a market in existence where there is none?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, I don't think it _should_ be any particular thing. But if there are costs, they need to be covered. Even if I only publish on my own web site, I need to pay for hosting and a domain. The one thing that I think publishers do provide is reviewing. That gives readers some confidence in a paper even before they start to absorb it. Another model of publishing would be that government covers all the cost from tax receipts, making everything free to read by anyone. That might have its own negatives, of course. Ideally, information should be free, but we don't know how to do that yet.

Comment: I feel like a lot of this answer is aimed at a period in time much before the present internet age.  It seems that one could deduce from your arguments the nonexistence of websites like the arXiv.  Since the arXiv does exist and does host papers essentially for free, your arguments seem fishy to me.  In fact you do not need even to pay the minimal price for your own website in order to publish your material on the internet.  Moreover, *publishers* don't *pay for* referees: *editors* do the work of finding and persuading referees, who provide that service *free of charge*.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark, please read it a bit more carefully. I was speaking of an alternate world in which all of the inputs were paid for, including reviewing. Note that the "review" if any, provided by arXiv isn't as comprehensive as that provided by print publishers. I don't think you can fairly argue that _there are no costs_. The question is about how to get them covered. The current model is clearly flawed. But editors, printers, etc. _are_ paid. Someone pays for arXiv hosting, of course. If authors are also paid, that has consequences that must be considered, not ignored.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark, and of course I agree, much of current practice _is_ obsolete in the internet age, but it hasn't yet disappeared, and won't until we can come up with some better model that covers the _reduced_ costs that still linger in the system.

Comment: "I was speaking of an alternate world in which all of the inputs were paid for, including reviewing. Note that the "review" if any, provided by arXiv isn't as comprehensive as that provided by print publishers." I'm a bit confused about why you're speaking about the past and alternate realities but not about the actual present.  Also, as I said above, I don't know of any reasonable sense in which the *publishers* are providing the refereeing.  Refereeing is a process that academics do for each other, which is organized by (most often unpaid) editors....

Comment: ....You are, aware, I trust, that there are reputable journals that are freely available online, and that the refereeing process for these journals is identical to that of the ones owned by the mainstream publishing companies?  If so: why do you keep saying that the *publishers* provide this service?

Comment: Just in case you are not aware: (i) editors, even of very prestigious journals, are **not** necessarily paid.  (ii) It is not clear why referees **should be paid**.  It is a service that professional academics (who are being paid for their research activities) provide to each other.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark, are you saying that these journals have _no costs whatever_ associated with them? No one pays? No one _is_ paid. No hosting charges are paid by anyone? No server maintenance is paid by anyone? No machines to be maintained, rented or bought? No cloud services required?  I don't think it is a realistic claim that _there are no costs_. There may be no costs to _you_ but that is not the same thing.

Comment: @Buffy In 2015, the arXiv received ~76,000 new articles, and its budget was about $826,000. You do the math. Of course there are costs. But they are basically negligible when compared to the obscene amounts that university libraries pay each year to greedy publishers. For comparison, my department's library budget alone was 110,000€ in 2017. Elsevier's profits – not income, profits – in 2017 exceeded a billion dollars. Yes, $1,000,000,000, nine zeroes, more than a thousand times the arXiv's budget. That money can certainly be better spent.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi and others. Please don't confuse me with someone who supports the current system. I am not that person. All I am doing is pointing out that other alternatives, as positive as they may seem, also have negative consequences that must be considered. Is publishing only on arXiv, for example, a viable path for a young academic. I've heard no one make that claim. Obscene? Yes. Better spent? Yes. No argument. But put an entire system together. That is a harder task. The inertia in the current system is about all that carries it. But it does support scholarship - somehow.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, in any system there are forces that must be balanced if it is to survive. The current system balances those forces imperfectly. But to design a system you must consider all the forces.

Comment: Of course I'm not saying that there are *no costs whatsoever*.  But there are alternatives currently in practice where the total costs are so small compared to the currently dominant system (Najib's comment explains that well) that emphasizing "there are always costs" seems weird and irrelevant to me.

Comment: I do not think "it's too hard to do" is a viable excuse. We're all smart people, surely we can come up with something. Regarding "it does support scholarship - somehow"; I think you mean scholarship supports these parasites. If people stopped submitting their papers there, they would go bankrupt, but if Elsevier or Springer folded, life would mostly go on as usual for most of us.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, please, sir, whom are you quoting ("it's too hard to do")? And as for my actual quote, please, take it as I said it, not as you would like it to be. I, sir, am not that person.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Though there are certainly exceptions in other areas, besides preprint services that lack peer review, I can not name a single reputable journal in my field that does not charge either readers or authors for publication.

Comment: @BryanKrause That might be a field thing then. In math there are a few (I mainly know about Documenta Math.). But certainly these are still in the minority.

Comment: @Bryan: I believe you and also find that very unfortunate.  In my field (mathematics) there are such journals -- I could name about half a dozen off the top of my head.  They are very much still in the minority compared to all the other journals, which is a frustrating situation.  However, there are more than enough to function as a proof of concept, which is why it is especially frustrating to hear arguments about why such journals could not possibly exist.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark, no one here has argued that "such journals could not possibly exist." Please.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I've really only ever heard of it in math. Publishing in math (and CS as well) is a whole lot different from other sciences, and I think those voices get overrepresented here a bit.

Comment: @najibIdrisse I get your point but now I wonder if it may be that Elsevier also publishes about a thousand times more papers than the arxiv (and handles probably more due to rejections).

Comment: @Dirk According to the report mentioned in Allure's [comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/116678/why-is-it-acceptable-that-publishers-sell-papers-they-didn-t-pay-for/116679#comment307269_116679), Elsevier received 1.6 million submissions in 2017, and published over 430 000 articles; according to [this page](https://arxiv.org/help/stats/2017_by_area/index) the arxiv received 123 000 submissions in 2017 (but it also gives a higher number than the one mentioned by Najib for 2015).

Answer (score 6):

It becomes more and more unacceptable to do this. Computer Science already freed itself to a large extent. Journals like the high impact [jmlr](http://www.jmlr.org/) and many others already proved that you don't need expensive publishers anymore for science. I published in both kinds of journals and the services are on the same level. Additionally, more and more funding sources prohibit publishing behind a paywall ([one example](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/361/6406/957)).

Answer (score 4):

It's acceptable because authors of scholarly papers accept it.

Consider a different kind of publishing: Is it acceptable that publishers print advertisements without paying the creators of the advertisement? Indeed, publishers demand that the creators of the advertisement pay THEM. How do they get away with this? Why don't advertisers refuse to supply magazines with ads unless they are paid for them?

The obvious reason is because the advertiser receives a benefit, or hopes to receive a benefit, from having the ad published. Namely, he hopes that it will generate sales that will more than cover the cost of publishing the ad.

So why don't authors of scholarly papers refuse to submit articles to journals unless they are paid for them? Because the authors of these papers believe that they receive a benefit from having their paper published. Namely, they get their discoveries and ideas "out there" and build a professional reputation.

To the author, the benefit of getting published is compensation itself. He doesn't need to also receive cash for him to consider it worth his while to submit his paper to a journal. There are plenty of authors who feel this way, so publishers have no incentive to offer cash. If publishers found that they had a hard time getting enough papers to fill their pages, one obvious option they'd consider would be paying for material. But as they apparently get plenty of articles without paying, they have no incentive to offer to pay.

Comment: The sentence is literally true. If authors accept the practice, then it is acceptable by definition.

Answer (score 3):

> I have never seen any other economic situation where someone sold something legally without paying for it in any way.

But they do. Maybe not adequately, but publishers pay for the papers that they sell by offering all their services to the researcher (editorial services, publishing services, marketing). It might be that a considerable part of the revenues of publishers is profit, but not everything. Even journals operated by scientific communities sometimes have to charge publication fees ([example](https://www.osapublishing.org/submit/review/pub_charge.cfm)). In the case of open access publications, the publication fee has to cover all the costs, even those in the future.

The most important aspect for the premium that scientists pay in top journals is mentioned in the [answer by Thomas](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/116679/54543) which is the "prestige" owned by these high ranking journals. That would be very difficult to change. People are judged by the amount of high ranking publications they have. Funding agencies ask for these publications and, on the other side, are willing to pay the publication charges. Publishers charge the amount they think they can get away with. There does not seem to be a trivial way out of it (delivering the same results, but for a lesser amount of money).

Since boycotting top journals doesn't pay off for the individual, it's clear that a solution would probably require concerted actions of many.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83273/discussion-on-answer-by-trilarion-why-is-it-acceptable-that-publishers-sell-pape).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it expected to be changed in the future? Do scientists want to change it, or is this accepted by more or less the whole community?

At least one scientist (who stepped down from a full tenured professorship) wants to change it; he wrote a blog post ["Why I stopped caring about peer review, and learned to love the work."](http://markburgess.org/blog_peer.html)

To excerpt this in part:

> Today, thanks to the Internet, the sharing of ideas is a free and open process, and readers can form their own judgements about the value of ideas, whether flawed or polished. A good idea does not have to be stamped and labelled to be approved, and science is done in communities, without the central control of anonymous judges and juries. Preprint archives (originally distributed on paper by SLAC) have now become ArXive.org and ResearchGate provides indexed community based services, more efficiently than gross amalgamations of diverse fields by journals on a monthly schedule.
>
> ...
>
> Science rarely waits for publications to appear anymore. The process is so painfully slow that when a publication appears, either everyone has already read it, or no one is going to. So much nonsense gets into print that it is scarcely a real accolade to be in print.
>
> It takes months or years for a paper to reach print, and who can afford academic journals anyway? So, why would we not think: what if I just self-published my idea in a blog or a website? I could simply ask a smaller circle of people to comment honestly. And it would be searchable by anyone who might stumble across it with the help of modern search engines. Use the archives and the new social sharing sites. Technology can take prejudice out of the equation.

The blog is more focused on the brokenness of the peer review process, but his suggested solutions take advantage of the Internet age and thereby also address the broken finance arrangements of journal publications.