Why do researchers accept the pay-to-publish, pay-to-read model, despite receiving no direct compensation?
I’ve been thinking about the publishing model in academia (particularly in physics, but this may apply more broadly). Researchers invest a significant amount of time and effort in conducting studies, writing up results, and submitting to journals. Yet, we often need to pay article processing charges (APCs) or page fees to have our work published. At the same time, these journals charge subscription or pay-per-view fees to readers who want access.
Even among open-access journals, authors typically pay fees up front, and—aside from the occasional honorarium or special grant—they still don’t receive direct payment from the publisher. It’s true that publishing in top journals can lead to indirect benefits—such as better job prospects, grant funding, or recognition from peers—but this isn’t the same as directly getting paid for the research articles themselves.
My questions are:

Why has this pay-to-publish, pay-to-read system endured so long, even though many researchers voice frustration about it?

Is it considered acceptable or even normal that authors are not paid for creating (and reviewing) content that publishers then sell?

How do indirect benefits (like career advancement, prizes, or grant opportunities) factor into justifying this system’s integrity?

Are there realistic, large-scale alternatives (e.g., “diamond open access,” society-funded journals, etc.) that can break this cycle without simply shifting the financial burden from reader to author?


I understand that producing a quality journal involves peer review, editorial services, and overhead costs, but it still feels counterintuitive to pay to publish my own work while also seeing readers pay to access it. I’d love to hear how others in academia reconcile these concerns or if there are viable reform movements that address them.

What would a sustainable alternative look like to you?

@Aruralreader Currently I neither have alternative, clear, sustainable solution... However, I still have feeling that contemporary system is somewhat unfair.

Interesting. You might clarify what somewhat unfair means to you. Anyway, great changes can come from wrestling with challenges and, if you do so, maybe something that’ll benefit us all will pop out. Good luck!

Physics is actually one of the fields in which publishing is often free.  Certainly it is in many of the best journals, including traditional The Physical Review family.  On the other hand, many lower quality open access journals have no other source of revenue than charging authors.

This question is similar to: Why is it acceptable that publishers sell papers they didn’t pay for?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also see https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/109003/why-are-academics-not-paid-royalties-on-published-research-papers-in-ieee-acm-e

Like Democracy, it is the worst system except for all the other ones we’ve tried. Apologies to Churchill.

People pay to publish in journals because publication in those journals gives them "credit": for jobs, for promotions, for grants, for prestige.
No one can unilaterally choose not to do this because they can't choose how others will judge them.
The pay-to-publish rather than pay-to-read model has largely arisen from organized pressure by funding agencies that mandate that work they fund must be broadly available; that precludes publishers making money on subscriptions, so they changed the business model to charge authors instead (very much simplifying this history and the combinations of ways that publishers make money, of course). So yes, if there is an organized push to change things they can change, but the end result of a change isn't necessarily what advocates intend or predict.

I completely agree that .... in practice. Career incentives (like credit for jobs, promotions, grants) lock researchers into this pay-to-publish model. However, my bigger question is: why do so few people actively challenge it? Even if it’s entrenched and reinforced by prestige, is there really no room—or will—for large-scale dissatisfaction that questions the underlying fairness or legitimacy of the system?

I would expect that those who are inconvenienced by the system of pay-to-publish and those who have the skills and resources to produce an alternative model are largely non-overlapping groups of people.

@K.R.Park I'd agree with Root's explanation. People are also just busy with a lot of other stuff - they don't have time to fix stuff they didn't personally break.

@K.R.Park publish or perish actively selects for those who invest in the current system, pushing anyone who would challenge it out of academia and any position to do anything about it.

@user1937198 I’m not sure this is true.  With notable exceptions most tenured researchers do not live by “publish or perish”.  They are just productive without falling into the “extreme publisher” category.

@ZeroTheHero but they got tenure by publishing. Therefore selecting those who have tenure tend not to be ones who would have made a fuss. Also, they still need to collaborate, and there collaborators need the high rank publications. It's not just numbers of publications, it's the need to have high impact journals.  And those journals are in the current system, and those without tenure need to be published in them.

@user1937198 all of this can indeed be taken to the extreme in some cases but your description is exagerated for most.  Very few people can deal with high publishing pressures for an extended period of time, and for most researchers there are slow times.  Not every researcher has a group of 40 slaves working around the clock…

@ZeroTheHero I don't understand what your argument is: what are you saying is not true? How does that apply to the subject matter here?

@BryanKrause I don’t believe that “publish or perish” is generally as bad as it is made out to be, and I certainly don’t believe it selects for those who invest in the current system to the detriment of some who would challenge the status quo. In fact I have come to believe the current system works reasonably well, although I do recognize there is a minority of very high profile greedy profiteer publishers who have figure out how to milk the system.

Basically there is a cost to producing a published paper.  In some cases the cost is excessive and vastly inflated, but I don’t see self-selection nor do I believe that everyone functions in the “publish or perish” model.  Certainly true some times, but not most of the time.

@ZeroTheHero how many postdocs will willingly publish in a lower impact journal if a higher impact journal is possible? That's where I see the main pressure point being. Postdocs don't have the flexibility to be picky about journals if they want to have a cv that keeps them in academia. It's not volume or slow periods. It's willingly self sacrificing you cv by avoiding high impact journals. That's how publish or perish weans out postdocs, who otherwise would be the group most likely to push for change.

Because in practice, no other model works better.  It takes time, money and resources to publish an article.  I don’t mean writing it or doing the research, but you need people to maintain websites, update softwares, deal with backups, and do all these other littles things that academics don’t like doing once the paper is submitted.  You need copy editors, programmers etc so papers use a single coherent format, to run spellcheckers and grammar checks, to check that references are consistent, figures are produced correctly, and the list goes on.   (See here for some insights into staffing a physics journal.)
Someone has to invest the time, and that’s money.   Volunteering only lasts so long : editors, associate editors etc eventually quit, so unless you have a permanent staff of specialists, the thing will unravel quickly once volunteers (legitimately) want to move on.
Would you prefer that a university researcher devote 5 hours to do all the prep work for publication, or is it more efficient to have a professional staffer from the journal do this?  You can go down the pecking order if you want and claim that a grad student or a university admin assistant could do this, but there is time involved and so again, would you pay your own employee to do this (most academics hate doing this!) or let a specialist from the journal do it?
Alternatives have been tried.  The journal Quantum referred to in the link above started as open-access with no APC and covered their costs through donations, but they now ask for APC although they are lenient if you cannot afford to pay.  If these guys charge APCs,  it’s because they need to.
So, the underlying question here is: how much and who should pay for access?  Certainly some publishers have very very fat margins and I will not deny that some publishers charge much too much for subscription or APCs.  (See Is the staggeringly profitable business of scientific publishing bad for science?, published in The Guardian in June 2017.). However many journal are run on a shoestring and would not survive without the volunteer help of editors and the income from subscription or APCs to pay the support staff.
As to why, well… it’s fairly rewarding,  Nevermind the prestige (real or imagined) that comes from this, it’s a way of giving back to the community.  Some people are asked to referee my submissions so one way I can contribute back is participating in the submission process at the editorial level.
Why do I do it for free?  Well… I don’t. I’m not like Stephen King or Tom Clancy: if they produce no novel they can’t buy bread. I on the other hand am paid to produce science - research is part of my job description, along with teaching, supervision and committee work.

Not too mention, that five hours is for someone who knows what they’re doing. Someone who doesn’t know whatever typesetting system the journal uses might take weeks to learn it. Waste of time

@AzorAhai-him- Yeah 5hrs is a minimum, but even this much is not an efficient way of allocating resources.  Too many people think publishing is just a plug-and-play process in large part because some cadre of professionals make it (almost) seamless for the authors.

Totally agreed. Just adding information. I think a lot of that sentiment seems to come from LaTeX-y field where authors are expected to do their own typesetting.

Hmmm... if I've spent 6 months writing a paper,  and the reviewers have each spent 8 hours reviewing each of 3 revisions,  then 5 hours seems pretty marginal as a % of the total time invested in the paper.  Also,  its not just an exceptional minority charging large amounts.  (In my field at least) the average APC is $3000-$4000, which would seem about right for 50 hours of work,  not 5

I also think you under estimate the effect of publish our perish. While tenured profs are some what immune,  the majority of systems don't have tenure,  and even in those that do,  the majority of researchers don't have tenure. If your are on a 2-3 year postdoc contract,  then you better be getting a paper every 2-3 years or you definitely will "perish" (professionally). Ditto those on "soft money positions". Finally publish our perish is literally baked into the system in some places.  Eg here those without 1 major output every 2/3 years are subject to the initiation of disciplinary action.

@IanSudbery … and despite this the journal probably made some changes.  You still need someone to update the manuscript tracking software, actually keep trance of all this, update the website etc.  Yes I do think some fees are excessive and honestly it’s a barrier for researchers with no funds but it’s not 0 work to run a journal.

my experience was that admin assistants and staff were shared between several journals to rationalize.  Nobody got reach running these journals although I am aware that some journals have healthy margins.

Finally, the UK and the US have strange systems.  Certainly in the UK there is quasi-tenure (you can be “reorganized away”) but with those exceptions most “Western” systems do not necessarily live by publish or perish.  Instructors are valuable (?) to the institution because of their teaching and mentoring and research is rarely 100% of the job description.  Agreed that no output is bad but you can have only a “reasonable” publication record and not perish.

The answer is very simple.
Do you have a better idea?
If you have a better idea, feel free to write it in the comments and if I think it's workable I'll see if I can set something up.
